# How do tellg() & tellp() work in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream

Why do `tellg()` and `tellp()` always come together? And how can we separate them from each other?

Comment: They're made for each other. Please dont separate them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: hi there,  actually this is my class question by our prof. he said that we can separate them from each other. but how?

Comment: @user3532286 It's more the opposite.  They are normally completely separate, members of different classes.

Comment: Ground both of them until the charge imbalance leaks away.

Answer (score 5):

*They don't.*

One indicates where the "get" cursor is in an input stream; the other indicates where the "put" cursor is in an output stream.

They are similar but not intrinsically linked, so the premise of your question is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, they're members of different classes: `tellg` is
a member of `std::istream`, and `tellp` is a member of
`std::ostream`.  The reason they have different names is because
there are classes (e.g. `std::iostream`) which derive from both
`std::istream` and `std::ostream`, and the functions may report
different values: an actual `std::streambuf` type may maintain
the read and write positions in sync (as does `std::filebuf`) or
keep them separate (as does `std::stringbuf`).

Answer (score 2):

One is for an input stream, the other for an output stream.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg
input stream position

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp
output stream position